# Dynamics 2011 SDK IServiceProvider

Tags: c#, sdk, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm writing a stand-alone service (not a plug-in, in the strictest sense) to periodically update Dynamics CRM 2011 using the SDK.

My code includes the following:

```cs
// Get entity metadata so we can process attributes correctly
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
... (etc)
```

This requires an instance of the ServiceProvider class [which implements IServiceProvider] but I have no idea how to get it.

So, how do I get it?

Thanks

[Edit]

I'm currently looking at using ServerConnection as an alternative.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309393.aspx

[/Edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it sorted.

From http://markuserlandsson.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/my-first-crm-2011-project-part-1/

(reproduced here for safety)

```
ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

IServiceConfiguration<IOrganizationService> config = 
        ServiceConfigurationFactory.CreateConfiguration<IOrganizationService>(
        new Uri(Properties.Settings.Default.CrmUrl));
config.CurrentServiceEndpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ProxyTypesBehavior());

OrganizationServiceProxy proxy = new OrganizationServiceProxy(config, credentials);
OrganizationServiceContext context = new OrganizationServiceContext(proxy);
```

Then use this `proxy` or `context` to do what you need.